# is sliding window protocol needs full duplex data flow?

Tags: networking, computer-science, sliding-window

Here is my question, in sliding window protocol for flow control in l2 osi model, it is necessary to establish a full duplex connection?
because i think at the same time that frames are sending ACK from receiver should transmit for example if window size is 5 when 3th frame is sending ACK of 1th one should sent by receiver!
that is right??

Comment: It is some transport, not data-link, layer protocols, e.g. TCP, that use windows and ACKs. Data-link (layer-2) protocols like ethernet do no such thing, and not all transport protocols have that, e.g. UDP.

Comment: But i learn this protocol in l2 osi model!! I still do not get it, at the same time ACK and frames should transfer and for such this flow we need to establish full duplex (I guess)?!!?!

Comment: You are looking at some "perfect" model. OSes do not implement the OSI model, and the layer-2 protocols that are used today do not implement the flow control you are looking at. There was an attempt by the IEEE to add some type of flow control to ethernet, but it is nothing like you describe; it is a simple pause frame to tell senders to pause sending. Ethernet flow control is poorly implemented and supported, but it has nothing like ACKs. You are studying a conceptual model that really does not exist.

Comment: thank you for you answer, i guess i got it :~)